# How to optimize recursive function for finding all permutations?

Tags: r, recursion, optimization, permutation

I wrote the following piece of code to find all permutations of a given vector:

```
perm <- function(v, r = NULL, P = NULL) {
  l <- length(v)
  if (l == 0) {
    P <- rbind(P, r)
    rownames(P) <- NULL
    P
  } else {
    for (i in 1:l) {
      new_r <- c(r, v[i])
      new_v <- v[-i]
      P <- perm(new_v, new_r, P)
    }
    P
  }
}

P <- perm(1:9) # takes "forever" yet e.g. perm(1:7) is quite fast!?!
P
```

It does what it should but the problem is that it kind of runs forever if one uses vectors of length > 8 (as above).

**My question**
I don't really see the problem, I found some recursive implementations that don't look so different yet are much more efficient... So is there a simple way to optimize the code so that it runs faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @akrun states, recursion in `R` is generally not that efficient. However, if you must have a recursive solution, look no further than `gtools::permutations`. Here is the implementation:

```
permGtools <- function(n, r, v) {
    if (r == 1) 
        matrix(v, n, 1)
    else if (n == 1) 
        matrix(v, 1, r)
    else {
        X <- NULL
        for (i in 1:n) X <- rbind(X, cbind(v[i], permGtools(n - 1, r - 1, v[-i])))
        X
    }
}
```

By the way, to get the full source code, simply type `gtools::permutations` in the console and hit enter. For more information see [How can I view the source code for a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19226816/4408538)

And here are some timings:

```
system.time(perm(1:8))
  user  system elapsed 
34.074  10.641  44.815

system.time(permGtools(8,8,1:8))
 user  system elapsed 
0.253   0.001   0.255
```

And just for good measure:

```
system.time(permGtools(9, 9, 1:9))
 user  system elapsed 
2.512   0.046   2.567
```

### Why is the OP's implementation slower?

Skip to the summary if you don't to read the details.

For starters, we can simply see that the OP's implementation makes more recursive calls than the implementation in `gtools`. To show this, we add `count <<- count + 1L` to the top of each function (N.B. We are using the `<<-` assignment operator which searches through the parent environments first). E.g:

```
permGtoolsCount <- function(n, r, v) {
    count <<- count + 1L
    if (r == 1)
    .
    .
```

And now we test a few lengths:

```
iterationsOP <- sapply(4:7, function(x) {
    count <<- 0L
    temp <- permCount(1:x)
    count
})

iterationsOP
[1]    65   326  1957 13700

iterationsGtools <- sapply(4:7, function(x) {
    count <<- 0L
    temp <- permGtoolsCount(x, x, 1:x)
    count
})

iterationsGtools
[1]   41  206 1237 8660
```

As you can see, the OP's implementation makes more calls in every case. In fact, it makes about `1.58...` times the amount of recursive calls.

```
iterationsOP / iterationsGtools
[1] 1.585366 1.582524 1.582053 1.581986
```

As we have stated already, recursion in `R` has a bad reputation. I couldn't find anything pinpointing exactly why this is the case other than [R does not employ tail-recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33453044/4408538).

At this point, it seems hard to believe that making about 1.58 times more recursive calls would explain the 175 times speed up we saw above (i.e. `44.815 / 0.255 ~= 175`).

We can profile the code with `Rprof` in order to glean more information:

```
Rprof("perm.out", memory.profiling = TRUE)
a1 <- perm(1:8)
Rprof(NULL)
summaryRprof("perm.out", memory = "both")$by.total
             total.time total.pct mem.total self.time self.pct
"perm"            43.42    100.00   15172.1      0.58     1.34
"rbind"           22.50     51.82    7513.7     22.50    51.82
"rownames<-"      20.32     46.80    7388.7     20.30    46.75
"c"                0.02      0.05      23.7      0.02     0.05
"length"           0.02      0.05       0.0      0.02     0.05



Rprof("permGtools.out", memory.profiling = TRUE)
a2 <- permGtools(8, 8, 1:8)
Rprof(NULL)
summaryRprof("permGtools.out", memory = "tseries")$by.total
             total.time total.pct mem.total self.time self.pct
"rbind"            0.34    100.00     134.8      0.18    52.94
"cbind"            0.34    100.00     134.8      0.08    23.53
"permGtools"       0.34    100.00     134.8      0.06    17.65
"matrix"           0.02      5.88       0.0      0.02     5.88
```

One thing that jumps out immediately (other than the time) is the huge memory usage of the OP's implementation. The OP's implementation uses roughly **15 Gb** of memory whereas the `gtools` implementation only use **134 Mb**.

### Digging Deeper

In the above, we are simply looking at memory usage in a general view by setting the memory parameter to `both`. There is another setting called `tseries` that lets you look at the memory usage over time.

```
head(summaryRprof("perm.out", memory = "tseries"))
     vsize.small vsize.large    nodes duplications       stack:2
0.02     4050448    25558992 49908432         2048 "perm":"perm"
0.04       98808    15220400  1873760          780 "perm":"perm"
0.06       61832    12024184  1173256          489 "perm":"perm"
0.08       45400           0   861728          358 "perm":"perm"
0.1            0    14253568        0          495 "perm":"perm"
0.12       75752    21412320  1436120          599 "perm":"perm"

head(summaryRprof("permGtools.out", memory = "tseries"))
     vsize.small vsize.large    nodes duplications              stack:2
0.02     4685464    39860824 43891512            0 "permGtools":"rbind"
0.04      542080      552384 12520256            0 "permGtools":"rbind"
0.06           0           0        0            0 "permGtools":"rbind"
0.08      767992     1200864 17740912            0 "permGtools":"rbind"
0.1       500208      566592 11561312            0 "permGtools":"rbind"
0.12           0      151488        0            0 "permGtools":"rbind"
```

There is a lot going on here, but the thing to focus on is the `duplications` field. From the documentation for `summaryRprof` we have:

> It also records the number of calls to the internal function duplicate in the time interval. duplicate is called by C code when arguments need to be copied.

Comparing the number of copies in each implementation:

```
sum(summaryRprof("perm.out", memory = "tseries")$duplications)
[1] 121006

sum(summaryRprof("permGtools.out", memory = "tseries")$duplications)
[1] 0
```

So we see that the OP's implementation requires many copies to be made. I guess this isn't surprising given that the desired object is a parameter in the function prototype. That is, `P` is the matrix of permutations that is to be returned and is constantly getting larger and larger with each iteration. And with each iteration, we are passing it along to `perm`. You will notice in the `gtools` implementation that this is not the case as it simply as two numeric values and a vector for its parameters.

### Summary

So there you have it, the OP's original implementation not only makes more recursive calls, but also require many copies which in turn bogs down the memory for drastic blows to efficiency.

Comment: So why is this Implementation so much faster than mine?

Comment: Great question! I will profile the 2 approaches when I get a chance. If I had to guess, I would say that your original implementation is slower because your recursion is occurring in pure `R`, whereas the gtools implementation takes advantage of `cbind` and `rbind`. This is an untested hunch though.

Answer (score 1):

It may be better to use `permGeneral` from `RcppAlgos`

```
P <- perm(1:5) # OP's function

library(RcppAlgos)
P1 <- permuteGeneral(5, 5)
all.equal(P, P1, check.attributes = FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

#### Benchmarks

On a slightly longer sequence

```
system.time({

   P2 <- permuteGeneral(8, 8)
  })
#user  system elapsed 
#  0.001   0.000   0.001 

system.time({

   P20 <- perm(1:8) #OP's function
})
# user  system elapsed 
# 31.254  11.045  42.226 

all.equal(P2, P20, check.attributes = FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Generally, recursive function can take longer time as recursive calls to the function takes more execution time

Comment: Thank you... but this doesn't really answer my question, right?!?